# Touchpad Scrolling doesn't work on vmware workstation 10 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, vmware, scrolling

I've read most of the scrolling issues that are here but non of them really works for me.
here is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse           id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

There is no trackpad/touchpad/mouse horizontal /vertical two or three or four fingers scrolling anywhere in the normal configuration...
It has to be configured somewhere; I just can't find it...

Comment: Reinstall the touchpad driver package: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`